Low-rank decomposition of matrices with all-one diagonal and small off-diagonal
Recently, I encountered a paper utilizing the concept of Kissing numbers from the perspective of matrices.
Specifically, the authors presented the Kissing numbers as follows.
Def: For a given $m \in \mathbb N$, the Kissing number $Kiss(m)$ is
$$Kiss(m) := \max_n \{n \in \mathbb N \mid \exists A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}, \|A_{i}\|_2 = 1, \langle A_{i}, A_{j} \rangle \leq \frac{1}{2}, \forall i \neq j\}.$$
This can be understood as a row-rank decomposition of near-identity matrices (specifically, in $A A^\top$, the diagonal entries are one and all the off-diagonal entries are at most $\frac{1}{2}$).
In the paper, the authors only showed the existence of such matrices $A$ but did not tell us how can we find such matrices with a theoretical guarantee.
What they did in the paper is basically using regularization.
Q: Can we have an explicit subset $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ such that for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, we have $\|A_{i}\|_2 = 1, \langle A_{i}, A_{j} \rangle \leq \frac{1}{2}, \forall i \neq j$?
A naive subset: We know that if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is orthonormal (i.e., $\|A_{i}\|_2 = 1, \langle A_{i}, A_{j} \rangle = 0, \forall i \neq j$), then $A A^\top$ is identity, but we must have $n \geq m$. This is related to the concept of the Stiefel manifold.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold

A naive superset: We know that if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is row-wise norm-1 (i.e., $\|A_{i}\|_2 = 1, \forall i$), then all the diagonal entries of $A A^\top$ are one. Here, $m$ can be as low as $1$, but we have no guarantee on $\langle A_{i}, A_{j} \rangle$ and thus no control on the off-diagonal entries of $A A^\top$ (we do have the naive bound $\langle A_{i}, A_{j} \rangle \leq 1$). This is related to the concept of the Oblique manifold.

https://www.manopt.org/manifold_documentation_oblique.html

Ref: Dröge, Hannah, et al. "Kissing to Find a Match: Efficient Low-Rank Permutation Representation." Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 36 (2024).
